# How I can eval a buffer and/or an instruction within Emacs with Swank and SLIME?

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank

I've successfully installed clojure-mode, slime, slime-repl within Emacs.
I start a swank server with "lein swank" and hang slime to it with "slime-connect". I can use the SLIME REPL to evaluating Clojure expression within the REPL.

How can I eval a single s-exp or a whole file (a.k.a I want to run a Clojure file withing Emacs and see the output in a dedicated frame or in the repl) showing the answer in the SLIME REPL?

For example I define a simple binding in a .clj file within my project directory:

```
(def my-bind [1 2 3])
```

Now I want SLIME to eval this expression in the repl, so if in the repl I write:

```
(first my-bind)
```

I want to obtain 1.
How can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To eval a single sexp, put your cursor in front of the last closing paren and hit `C-x C-e`. There is another one to evaluate a surrounding sexp, but I can't for the life of me remember it.

To evaluate the whole file, do `C-c C-k`

Comment: This is the black magic of computers.. I've done what you have suggested like 1000 times and it never worked.. now it works o.O thank you very much :)

Answer (score 9):

What Rayne said, and there's M-C-x to evaluate the top level expression which the cursor is in.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, Emacs is freaking awesome :D